# fullCalendar.js: Show events by selected dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I'm using fullCalendar 1.6.1 and fetching events from google calendar with gcal. 
I'm trying to fetch event information for selected dates to be shown on a separated div.

```
select: function (startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        $('.tasksDiv').text(/* Events' info here*/) }
```

So basically I have a `calendarDiv` and a `tasksDiv`, I want to show all the events in the selected(user triggered) dates on the `tasksDiv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. For some reason I thought fullCalendar.js has a built-in way to do it, but here is my solution:

```
select: function (startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    var pulledEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    for(var i=0; i<pulledEvents.length; i++) {
      if(pulledEvents[i].start.toString() == startDate.toString()){
        $('.tasksDiv').append(pulledEvents[i].title)
      } 
    };
}
```

So `clientEvent` calls for all calendar's events, then the loop looks for the the date match. it wouldn't work if you don't convert `pulledEvents` to a string to fit the `selcted`'s `startDate`.